# Set focus to an input field in iOS/Safari

Tags: c#, ios, selenium-webdriver, safari, appium

I am trying to automate tests on iOS 12.3.1 on Safari browser using RemoteWebDriver. I have a real device (iPad) and using Appium version 1.13.0. When I execute `element.SendKeys("some text")`, it's not triggering the MVC apps character length validation. Then I tried using Actions (OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions) and figured out that, `Action.SendKeys(...)` trigger the character length validation if I can set focus into the input field. (When I set the focus manually, The iOS/iPad's keyboards get activated and comes to the screen and plus the cursor starts blicking inside the input element). I want to simulate the same behavior to send keys using actions.

I have tried so many options including `javascript .focus()` and nothing seems to work to get the focus to the input field. The element itself has autofocus attribute, but still no luck. Any advise ?

This is how I initialized the remote web driver

```
case "SafariOniOS":
                    var iOSCaps = new DesiredCapabilities();
                    iOSCaps.SetCapability("platformName", "iOS");
                    iOSCaps.SetCapability("platformVersion", Settings.PlatformVersion);
                    iOSCaps.SetCapability("browserName", MobileBrowserType.Safari);
                    iOSCaps.SetCapability("automationName", "XCUITest");
                    iOSCaps.SetCapability("udid", Settings.DeviceId);
                    iOSCaps.SetCapability("deviceName", Settings.DeviceName);
                    iOSCaps.SetCapability("xcodeOrgId", Settings.AppleDeveloperTeamId);
                    iOSCaps.SetCapability("xcodeSigningId", "iPhone Developer");
                    iOSCaps.SetCapability("newCommandTimeout", 360);

                    var iOSCommandExecutor = new SomeCommandExecutorImpl(
                        new Uri(Settings.RemoteServerAddress),
                        Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan)
                    {
                        CommandsToIgnore = SomeCommandExecutor.CommandsToIgnoreForMobileWeb
                    };
                    return new RemoteWebDriver(iOSCommandExecutor, iOSCaps);
```